# Using mtime other than with FIND

Tags: unix, solaris

I am trying to write a script which will move files older than 1 day to an archive directory. I used the following `find` command:

```
for filename in `find /file_path/*.* -type f -mtime +1`
```

This fails since my argument list is too big to be handled by `find`. I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/find: arg list too long
```

Is it possible to use `find` in an `IF-ELSE` statement? Can someone provide some examples of using `mtime` other then in `find`.

*Edit: To add the for loop of which the find is a part.*

Comment: Is that trailing backtick a copy-paste mistake? Without it, it works for me. Also, why the `*.*`, just use *.

Comment: the find is a part of a for loop. edited the question.

Comment: @tjameson: use '`*.*`' to avoid names that do not contain a dot.

Comment: Aww, files without dots are people too ;)

Comment: @tjameson: but those 'people' aren't as dotty as their relatives and aren't as much fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /file_path -name '*.*' -mtime +1 -type f |
while read filename
do ...move operation...
done
```

That assumes your original code was acceptable in the way it handled spaces etc in file names,
and that there is no sensible way to do the  move in the action of `find`.  It also avoids problems with overlong argument lists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..it's not giving an argument list long error...but, it seems like reading all the files in the sub directories also..my file_path is /jobs/20110808/logs, but it's also reading from jobs/20110807, jobs/20110809 etc..Should I add depth also?

Comment: @user295338: specify `/jobs/20110808/logs` if that is were you want it to search.  `find` looks under the places you ask it to look.

Comment: Oops...sorry about that..I have given the directory as /jobs/logs/ and I need to look for files only in this directory. But find is going into the sub directories (like /jobs/logs/20110807, /jobs/logs/20110805 etc) and reading from those directories also.

Comment: @user295338: then `-depth 1` is appropriate.  (In this context, I think the answer applies to Solaris too.)

Comment: Thanks Jon..but it doesn't seem to work..Here's the man page for find from Solaris...http://www.bga.org/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/man/solaris/find.1.html

Comment: @user295338: OK; I had forgotten how retrograde the Solaris software is.  Given the documentation, there is nothing available short of installing GNU find and using that - or using grep to weed out unwanted names (too many slashes).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the -exec part of find?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to cp files, you could use

find /file_path -name "*.*" -mtime +1 -type f | xargs -i mv {} /usr/local/archived